# How to store the triples in 4store

Tags: django, debian, sparql, rdfstore, 4store

```
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_gstudio-0.3.dev-py2.7.egg/gstudio/testing1.py", line 129, in rdf_description
    store.add(self,(subject, predicate, object),context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib-3.2.0-py2.7.egg/rdflib/plugins/memory.py", line 298, in add
    Store.add(self, triple, context, quoted)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib-3.2.0-py2.7.egg/rdflib/store.py", line 177, in add
    def add(self, (subject, predicate, object), context, quoted=False):
in 

store.add(self, (subject, predicate, object), context, quoted=False)
```

Comment: Please can you describe your issue a bit better ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK - rdflib does not support 4store. But you can easily assert the triples using `curl` and python and the 4store [SPARQL Server](http://4store.org/trac/wiki/SparqlServer). Here there is an example:

```
 import subprocess
 command = ["curl","-s",
            "-T","/some/file/with/triples",
            "-H","Content-Type: application/x-turtle",
            "http://localhost:port/data/http://graph.to/save/triples"]

  p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  output, err = p.communicate()
  ret = p.poll()
  if ret <> 0:
     raise Exception, "Error asserting triples"
```

In this example the content type is [turtle](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/) but you can use any of the other RDF serializations (`ntriples`, `rdfxml`).

If you do not want to deal with subprocesses you can also translate this call into a `urllib/urllib2` function.

There are more examples in the [4store SparqlServer documentation](http://4store.org/trac/wiki/SparqlServer). And, optionally, you can use any of the [Python 4store client libraries](http://4store.org/trac/wiki/ClientLibraries).

Comment: i have not used subprocess.. instead preferred urllib/urllib2 function.